# Merge row cells after Summing up multiple rows by grouping in ssrs

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a matrix report in SSRS which is grouped by Product Class, Tax Type and Depot Name as shown in the following image.
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to get the sum of both the Order Volume and Marker Volume based on the tax type grouping and populate them respectively in the order volume total and marker volume total fields.
So I put the following queries for them respectively:

=Sum(Fields!OrderVolume.Value, "TaxType")

=Sum(Fields!MarkerVolume.Value, "TaxType")

I then got the total as expected but it's splitting. How can I merge both of them (order volume total and marker volume total) based on the Tax Type?

Kindly help,

Best Regards

Comment: It looks like the table is also grouping by Product Class or Marker Code. You would need to remove the extra grouping so Tax Type is the child and Depot the parent Group.

Comment: Assuming you want to still show the product class detail, then remove the product class group, choose `group only` if prompted when deleting. Then add a total to your tax type group (right-click the tax type group in the rowgroup panel under main design area). This won;t give you exactly what you want but it's a reasonable compromise. Unfortunately, you cannot merge rows outside the scope of a group.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got the expected result for both the order volume total and marker volume total fields after trying what you said however the product class doesn't show all details. @AlanSchofield

Comment: @HannoverFist Thanks for your response too but I need to show all extra groupings in the report.

Comment: Show your report design and output as it it now, highlighting what is wrong. When you show your design, make sure to include the rowgroup panel below the main design window and show what grouping is set on each group.

Comment: @Somad - To show all the groupings but keep the Order Volume by the Tax Type, you would need to create a new column to the right of Tax Type but in the same group and use `=Sum(Fields!OrderVolume.Value)`. Then do the same for Marker Volume.